# Terraform append item in a map

Tags: terraform

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
school = {
  "class1" = {
    "student" = {
      "name" : ["J", "B"]
    }
  }
  "class2" = {
    "student" = {
      "name" : ["Y", "X"]
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is loop over this object and append the same value to the end of each of the values in "name", so I would end up with something like this:

```
school = {
  "class1" = {
    "student" = {
      "name" : ["J-appendValue", "B-appendValue"]
    }
  }
  "class2" = {
    "student" = {
      "name" : ["Y-appendValue", "X-appendValue"]
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be as follows:

```
locals {

  school = {
    "class1" = {
      "student" = {
        "name" : ["J", "B"]
      }
    }
    "class2" = {
      "student" = {
        "name" : ["Y", "X"]
      }
    }
  }
  
  append_value = "appendValue"
  
  school_merged = {for k, v in local.school: 
                    (k) => {student = {
                        name = [for name in v["student"].name: "${name}-${local.append_value}"] 
                       }}
                   }

}

output "test" {
    value = local.school_merged
}
```

gives:

```
test = {
  "class1" = {
    "student" = {
      "name" = [
        "J-appendValue",
        "B-appendValue",
      ]
    }
  }
  "class2" = {
    "student" = {
      "name" = [
        "Y-appendValue",
        "X-appendValue",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Love this, thanks!